# CTE recursively update field values until no default value left

Tags: recursion, sql-update, common-table-expression

I'm trying to write a recursion that updates a field's values until no default value of '0' is left.

The starting point is this table:

```
    USE [Test]

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [Test].[dbo].[T0]

    CREATE TABLE [Test].[dbo].[T0] (
    ID1 nvarchar(50),
    ID2 nvarchar(50),
    Score decimal(18,0),
    tag int
    );

    INSERT INTO [Test].[dbo].[T0] (ID1, ID2, Score, tag)
    VALUES ('A1', 'B1', 100.0, 0),
    ('A1', 'B2', 90, 0),
    ('A2', 'B1', 80, 0),
    ('A2', 'B3', 70, 0),
    ('A3', 'B4', 85, 0),
    ('A4', 'B4', 75, 0),
    ('A5', 'B5', 85, 0),
    ('A5', 'B6', 75, 0);
```

The task for all rows with [tag] = 0 is to:

1. update the value of the field [tag] to '1' to the row with the highest score,
2. update the value of the field [tag] to '2' to rows having the same [ID1] or [ID2] as the row with the highest score.

> The recursion should continue until there are no more rows with the value '0'.

The desired output looks like this:

```
ID1 ID2 Score   tag
A1  B1  100 1
A1  B2  90  2
A2  B1  80  2
A2  B3  70  1
A3  B4  85  1
A4  B4  75  2
A5  B5  85  1
A5  B6  75  2
```

I have written the following CTE, which doesn't loop. I have to run it four times to get to the right output.

```
WITH T1 AS
(
    Select distinct [ID1], [ID2], [Score], [tag]
    ,Rank() over (order by [Score] desc, [ID1] desc, [ID2] desc) as [rk]
    from [Test].[dbo].[T0] 
    where [tag] = 0
    group by [ID1], [ID2], [Score], [tag]

)
,T2 AS
(
    Select distinct [ID1], [ID2]
    ,[Score]
    ,[rk]
    ,case when rk = 1 then 1 else [tag] end as [tag]
    from [T1]
)

,T3 AS
(
    Select [ID1], [ID2], [Score], 0 as rk, case when rk <> 1 and ([Top_ID1] is not null or [Top_ID2] is not null) then 2 else [tag] end as [tag]
    from 

        (Select [ID1], [ID2], [Score], rk, tag from [T2]) T3_1
        left outer join
        (Select  [ID1] as [Top_ID1], [ID2] as [Top_ID2] from [T2] where  rk = 1) T3_2
        on T3_1.[ID1] = T3_2.[Top_ID1] or T3_1.[ID2] = T3_2.[Top_ID2]
)
,T4 AS
(
    Select distinct [ID1], [ID2], [Score], [rk], [tag] 
    from [T3]
    where [tag] = 0 

    union all

    Select [ID1], [ID2], [Score], [rk], [tag] 
    from [T4]
    where [tag] = 0 
)
Update [Test].[dbo].[T0]
Set [tag] = [T4].[tag]
from [T4]
join [Test].[dbo].[T0] D on D.[ID1] = [T4].[ID1] and D.[ID2] = [T4].[ID2]
option ( MaxRecursion 0 );
```

> Would anyone know how to amend the code for the recursion to work?

Thanks for your help!